# Use Webclient with custom HttpMessageReader to synchronously read responses

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

## Problem

I have defined a `CustomHttpMessageReader` (which implements [`HttpMessageReader<CustomClass>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/HttpMessageReader.html)), which is able to read a multipart response from a server and converts the received parts into an object of a specific class. The `CustomHttpMessageReader` uses internally the [`DefaultPartHttpMessageReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.html) to actually read/parse the multipart responses.

The `CustomHttpMessageReader` accumulates the parts read by the DefaultReader and converts them into the desired class `CustomClass`.

I've created a `CustomHttpMessageConverter` that does the same thing for a `RestTemplate`, but I struggle to do the same for a `WebClient`.

I always get the following Exception:

```java
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockFirst(Flux.java:2600)
    at com.company.project.deserializer.multipart.CustomHttpMessageReader.readMultipartData(CustomHttpMessageReader.java:116)
    at com.company.project.deserializer.multipart.CustomHttpMessageReader.readMono(CustomHttpMessageReader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readToMono$14(BodyExtractors.java:211)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    ...
```

Mind you, I'm not interested in running `WebClient` asynchronously. I'm only future proofing my application because `RestTemplate` is apparently [only in maintenance mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) and the folks at Pivotal/Spring suggest using `WebClient` instead.

## What I Tried

As I understand, there are threads that are not allowed to be blocked, namely the netty-nio one in the exception. I tried removing netty from my dependencies, so that I can rely solely on Tomcat. That however doesn't seem to help, as I get another exception, explaining me, that no suitable `HttpConnector` exists (exception thrown by the WebClient.Builder)

```java
No suitable default ClientHttpConnector found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default ClientHttpConnector found
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.initConnector(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:297)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.build(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:266)
    at com.company.project.RestClientUsingWebClient.getWebclient(RestClientUsingWebClient.java:160)
```

I've tried my code executed in a unit test as well, as starting a whole Spring context. The result is unfortunately the same.

---

## Setup

To provide a bit more details, the following are snippets from the Classes mentioned earlier. The classes are not shown fully in order to understand better what is going on. All necessary methods are implemented (like e.g. `canRead()` in the Reader).

### `CustomHttpMessageReader`

I also included in the class the usage of `CustomPart` (in addition to `CustomClass`) just to show, that the content of the `Part` is also read i.e. blocked.

```java
public class CustomHttpMessageReader  implements HttpMessageReader<CustomClass> {

    private final DefaultPartHttpMessageReader defaultPartHttpMessageReader = new DefaultPartHttpMessageReader();

    @Override
    public Flux<CustomClass> read(final ResolvableType elementType, final ReactiveHttpInputMessage message,
                                  final Map<String, Object> hints) {
        return Flux.merge(readMono(elementType, message, hints));
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<CustomClass> readMono(final ResolvableType elementType, final ReactiveHttpInputMessage message,
                                      final Map<String, Object> hints) {
        final List<CustomPart> customParts = readMultipartData(message);
        return convertToCustomClass(customParts);
    }

    private List<CustomPart> readMultipartData(final ReactiveHttpInputMessage message) {
        final ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClass(byte[].class);
        return Optional.ofNullable(
                        defaultPartHttpMessageReader.read(resolvableType, message, Map.of())
                                .buffer()
                                .blockFirst()) // <- EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE!
                .orElse(new ArrayList<>())
                .stream()
                .map(part -> {
                    final byte[] content = Optional.ofNullable(part.content().blockFirst()) //<- HERE IS ANOTHER BLOCK
                            .map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer)
                            .map(ByteBuffer::array)
                            .orElse(new byte[]{});

                    // Here we cherry pick some header fields
                    return new CustomPart(content, someHeaderFields);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

### Usage of `WebClient`

```java
class RestClientUsingWebClient  {

    /**
     * The "Main" Method for our purposes
     */
    public Optional<CustomClass> getResource(final String baseUrl, final String id) {
        final WebClient webclient = getWebclient(baseUrl);

        //curl -X GET "http://BASE_URL/id" -H  "accept: multipart/form-data"
        return webclient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(id).build()).retrieve()
                .toEntity(CustomClass.class)
                .onErrorResume(NotFound.class, e -> Mono.empty())
                .blockOptional() // <- HERE IS ANOTHER BLOCK
                .map(ResponseEntity::getBody);

    }

    //This exists also as a Bean definition
    private WebClient getWebclient(final String baseUrl) {
         final ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder() 
                 .codecs(codecs -> {
                     codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024);
                     codecs.customCodecs().register(new CustomHttpMessageReader()); // <- Our custom reader
                 }) 
                 .build();

         return WebClient.builder()
                 .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                 .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
                 .build();
    }
}
```

### Usage of `build.gradle`

For the sake of completion, here is what I think is the relevant part of my `build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'  // <- This 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    // What I tried:
    // implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'){
    //    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty'
    //}
...
}
```

Comment: the error is crystal clear, the interface functio `Mono<CustomClass> readMono` returns a `Mono<T>` which means it is a reactive function that is run within a NON-Blocking `Webclient`. Just because your application is blocking does not mean that the `WebClient` is blocking. Its still internally non-blocking. In reactive programming we don't use Optionals, Streams etc. You are coding regular imperative Java in a reactive interface. Thats your problem. Dont block in a reactive interface

Comment: @Toerktumlare well gosh darn it! I forgot to mention, that I already tried doing the Reader fully reactive and it still didn't work. However, after inspecting my previous commits a realized I forgot to remove the 'blockFirst()' in  the readMultipartData() method. After changing that, it finally worked. Thanks a lot! If you want, you can formulate your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Tomorrow I'll add more details/code for other people in case they encounter similar problems. For now I'll head to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we look in the stacktrace that you provided we see these 3 lines

```
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockFirst(Flux.java:2600)
at com.company.project.deserializer.multipart.CustomHttpMessageReader.readMultipartData(CustomHttpMessageReader.java:116)
at com.company.project.deserializer.multipart.CustomHttpMessageReader.readMono(CustomHttpMessageReader.java:101)
```

They should be read from bottom to top. So what do they tell us?

The bottom line tells us that the function `readMono` on the line `101` in the class `CustomHttpMessageReader.java`was called first.

That function then called the function `readMultipartData` on line `116` in the class `CustomHttpMessageReader`(same class as above)

Then the function `blockFirst` was called on line `2600` in the class `Flux`.

Thats your blocking call.

So we can tell that there is a blocking call in the function `readMultipartData`.

So why cant we block in the function? well if we look in the API for the interface that function is overriding [HttpMessageReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/HttpMessageReader.html) we can se that the function returns a `Mono<T>` which means that the function is an `async` function.

And if it is `async` and we `block` we might get very very bad performance.

This interface is used within the `Spring WebClient` which is a fully `async` client.

You can use it in a non-async application, but that means you can block outside of the `WebClient` but internally, it needs to operate completely async if you want it to be as efficient as possible.

So the bottom line is that you should not block in any function that returns a `Mono` or a `Flux`.